# Is there an easy way to look up /proc/cpuinfo output for every x86-64 instance type on AWS, Azure and GCP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, cpu-architecture

I want to know the features supported by the CPU of every x86-64 / amd64 server I can rent on AWS, Azure and GCP. To decide which compilation flags are safe to use to produce binaries that would work on the oldest currently available instance types.

I can create server instances myself, run `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and destroy the instances. But I wonder, maybe someone has compiled the answers already and has shared them?

I assume the smallest size of every instance type is the same CPU as the largest, and that the same hardware is used in all regions. Is that true?

I also assume there won't be surprises like "usually you get a server with one CPU, but randomly sometimes you get a server with an older CPU with different supported features, for the same price!". Does anyone know of a counterexample?

Info about other big cloud vendors is welcome, but I'm mostly interested in those three.

Comment: Some cloud vendors spec at least some of their instance types by CPU microarchitecture, e.g. when Skylake-AVX512 was new, you could specify an instance with that specifically on google-cloud.  On AWS, where https://godbolt.org/ runs, `-march=native` is sometimes SKX (or Ice Lake these days), but recently is also sometimes Zen 3 (so manual use of AVX-512 will crash if you use Godbolt's "run the executable" feature and used AVX-512 intrinsics.)  I don't know what instance type they use, and if there would be a way to ensure a higher baseline.

Comment: You should embrace the Cloud Native Paradigm. Which insists on having the application adapt to the environment. While the provider can allow for provision machines with specific features, the whole point of a cloud is that you get a more or less *random* machine and your application should adapt to it. I don't know if any provider will let you fix the CPU microarchitecture, seems unlikely. It may be best to compile the software directly on the provisioned instances (or use CPU dispatchers).